# value in textbox not showing in winform

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm passing value from a method to a forms constructor and to a textbox but it is not showing in a textbox. Please help

myhub.cs

```
public void sendtoserver(string msg)
{
   Clients.Caller.stos(msg);
   Form1 frm = new Form1(msg);
}


public Form1(string msg)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   textBox1.Text = msg;
}
```

Comment: the value is showing on debugging

Comment: Instead of "msg" assign some text and check

Comment: please write an example of what are you saying

Comment: is that `Form1` is showing?

Comment: You are assigning string variable "msg" right, instead of that just put some text and check

Comment: yes form1 is already showing , just i need to get the value from this method and put it in a textbox thats it

Comment: is the `sendtoserver` method inside the `Form1` class?

Comment: Based on your last comment it sounds like the form is already open and you're trying to update the text box on it. Is that correct? If that's the case, you need a reference to the Form1 that's already open. In your code you're creating a new instance of Form1 that's never being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create an instance for Form1, since you are already on the form, just assign the msg to textBox1

```
public void sendtoserver(string msg)
{
   Clients.Caller.stos(msg);
   textBox1.Text = msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have To show the form too.

```
Form1 frm = new Form1(msg);
frm.Show();
```

Comment: so how do you open/show the form ? can you share the code.